# Login failed for user 'xxx' in Sql Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2. I logged  using 'sa'. I want to execute the following query

```
EXECUTE master..xp_cmdshell 
'bcp "SELECT * FROM LogicalDevice ORDER BY Id;" queryout "D:\filename.txt" -C RAW -R -c -w -T'
```

Basically I want to store all the data in text file which resides in the said location in the query. But I am facing the problem as below.

```
Warning: -w overrides -c.
SQLState = 28000, NativeError = 18456
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Native Client][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'.
```

I have also set permission from server using Windows Authentication Mode mode then Right Click on SQL Server Instance > Properties > Security > select Sql Server & Windows Authentication Mode and restarted the Sql Server and as well as Sql Agent. But the problem remains same as above.

Anyone having any solution. Please, help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Even when I am logged on using Windows Authentication, the error remains same.

Comment: Besides, the parameters also different in nature.